# RoundhousE - run view before function

Tags: sql, view, user-defined-functions, roundhouse

We are using RoundhousE for quite some time now, and a recently a problem came up.
We now have view files which contain calls to functions, and function that use views.
RoundhousE runs the functions files before the view files, so functions which have calls to view fails when 
there is an update to a view (new column added to it for example).

Is there a way to tell just for a specific function to run a view file first ?

How can we solve this cyclic problem ? (no matter if functions are run before views or the other way around, we would still fail ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a folder called runFirstAfterUp - this is where you put the things that will need to be run out of order.

https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/GettingStarted